# Python how to assign a copy of a class to a variable? (Instead of by reference)

Tags: python, class

I have a list containing the same class but instantiated with different variables. Further along my code I am basically trying to get a template of one of classes in that list and then resetting some member variables. However, when I modify what I think is a copy of the class, its still affecting the original class within the list. This is making me think that I haven't successfully created a class but only a reference. How can I make a true copy of it so that they are not connected in any way?

Here is a basic (and hopefully understandable) schematic of the list of class datastructure:

```
ListofClass = [classA(1,2), classA(34,21), classA(55,32)]
```

And then here is the code further along:

```
def getClass(position):
    templateclass = ListofClass[position]
    templateclass.var1 = "BLAH"
```

After this part of the code, my ListofClass is also changed as the value "BLAH" is in it. This is not the intended outcome!

Many thanks.

Comment: You have a list of _objects_, not of classes.

Comment: Are you asking how to deep copy an object or a list?

Comment: OK I will amend my question, do you anything else to add that could help me to solve this? I'm obviously a beginner.

Comment: I am asking how to deep copy an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of the quick comment discussion.

What we want to do is make use of the `deepcopy` method.

```
from copy import deepcopy

#snip
templateclass = deepcopy(ListofClass[position])
```

Alternatively we can define our own deepcopy method for returning a fresh class instance. Actually even using the above we'd probably need to define `__deepcopy__`

In the general sense we want to define an operation such that we return a new class instance container deepcopies of all the internal class data of the original. If we break it down piecewise like that, what we want to do internally, is call the constructor to build a legitimately new object and then somehow set its values to be the same as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Use **deepcopy** to copy, instead of creating reference by assigning.

**Solution:**

```
from copy import deepcopy

B = [class_A, class_B, class_C]
A = deepcopy(B)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>>
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b1 = a
>>> b2 = deepcopy(a)
>>> b1.append(50)
>>> b2.append(51)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 50]
>>> b1
[1, 2, 3, 50]
>>> b2
[1, 2, 3, 51]
```

Observe how modifying b1 also modifies the value to a. Appending to b2 however did not modify a.

Comment: This is true in general, but there's a few special cases where `deepcopy` won't work out of the box.

Comment: I don't think that is applicable for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out tahnks to Dylan Lawrence. I am using the copy module and then the copy.deepcopy function.

I modified my function so that its:

```
import copy

def getClass(position):
    templateclass = copy.deepcopy(ListofClass[position])
    templateclass.var1 = "BLAH"
```

Comment: I added a quick fleshed out answer, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
copied_list = copy.deepcopy(list_of_classes)
```

might be enough?